# The interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is equivalent to the set of real numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) \sim \mathbb{R}$, where $\sim$ represents [equivalence of sets](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aSet_Equivalence).

I tried to define a function $f\colon\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\to\mathbb{R}$ by the trigonometric function $\sin(x)$ which is one-to-one but fails to be onto; then I tried to define another function $g\colon(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ but faced the same problem of showing its surjectivity. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable how do you show that a set is equivalent to it??

Comment: try $f=\tan(x)$ on the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: You mean in bijection? Have you seen the stereographic projection?

Comment: Oh, $tan(x)$ does the job, hadn't thought of that, my mind was clearly elsewhere!!!

Comment: Obviously the answer to the question in the title is no. The question in the body is completely different. You may want to clarify.

Comment: Now by rescaling you have shown that any interval is equinumerous with $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that two sets are equivalent, there are two common methods:

1. Show that there is an explicit bijective function between the two sets.
2. Use the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder_Theorem) and two functions ($A$ to $B$ and $B$ to $A$) which are both injective, but not necessarily surjective.

In your case, I would have a good look at the $\tan x$ function (although there are others).

Answer (score 4):

The tangent function has a nice feature for what you want:  over a finite domain it has an infinite range.  Can you see how to use it?

Another approach is to think about the fact that $\frac 1{\frac \pi 2-x}$ goes to $+\infty$ at one end of your interval.  You can do something similar at the other end and be there.  this is useful in other cases.

Comment: The nice thing about the other approach is that the proof is much simpler.